# Is it possible to connect multiple QTcpSockets to a single QThread?

Tags: c++, qt, networking, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

So, I recently got into Qt networking/socket programming. I firstly had a server which just set up a new QTcpThread for every incoming connection and echoed input back.

But I kind of want to make a server where sockets(users) can log into different "chatrooms". My presumption is that you can make a "chatroom" with a QThread(then the thread just sends the data to all sockets on the thread).

So my questions are:
1: Can you connect multiple sockets to one thread?

2: If I can do that, how do I connect the client to the thread. I have tried to start up the thread with "MyThread *thread =  new MyThread(socketDescriptor);", but then I can't connect to it with other than the socket with that exact socketDescriptor. - So, how do I give the thread either the socketdescriptor or socket?

So, how do I somehow get the id(socketdescriptor, socket) of the socket connectiong to the thread? That is what i can't figure out.

Comment: Can a user join multiple chat rooms? if allowed, how would you handle that? would solve that using cross-thread communication? if this happens frequently, you incur a communication overhead that exceeds the performance gain you might be expecting from distributing your load across multiple threads...

Comment: Thank you for comment. No, a user cannot join multiple chatroom. I will just send the client back to the main server. The user joins a chatroom by writing stuff to the server. That I got figured out. But how do I connect the clients to a chatroom?

Comment: Probably a silly question but... why do you think you need to use threads for this at all?

Comment: Honestly, I dont really know for sure. I think it's because it's easier to handle alot of clients like that. They connect to a thread, the thread sends the Data to all the other clients in the thread.